# Google Apps Directory Sync Exclusion with Regex

Tags: g-suite

I am using the newly released Google Apps School Directory Sync to synchronise student and staff accounts from our school management system to our Google Apps for Education Domain.

The SDS tool is also to create the necessary class groups. This process is working well and the users and groups are being formed correctly in Google Apps.

There are a number of users that are not in the school management system. These I have placed in a folder and created a "Substring" exclusion rule. These users are ignored from the synchronisation as required.

I have a few groups that I have created on Google Apps which do not exist in our school management system - notably staff and committee groups. I now need a way to exclude these groups from deletion.

All the GASDS-created groups begin with `school-`. Essentially, I would like to exclude every group that does not begin with `school-`.

My first attempt was to enter a RegEx exclusion for the group email address: `^school-.*@schooldomain.edu`. I also attempted without the domain: `^school-.*`.

Using the "Simulate sync" option, the SDS tool indicates that my manually created groups will be deleted.

How can I enter in these exclusion rules to keep my manual groups (and any future manually created groups) safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do something very similar using GADS.  Our course group email addresses are prefixed with `course.`.  Your regexes would match groups which *contain* those, not match groups which do not contain.  Instead, use a [negative look ahead regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Under "Google Apps Configuration", "Exclusions", choose "Add Exclusion Rule". Select Type "Group Email Address" and Match Type "Regular Expression".  Use `^(?!school-).+` as the expression rule. This will exclude all Google Apps groups with email addresses that do not begin with the string `school-`.

[image]